# Agrupar resultados select hasta registro diferente

Tags: sql-server, select

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber si podrían ayudarme con esta consulta, tengo una tabla donde se muestran diversos datos, lo que requiero es que agrupe según idServicio, pero si vuelve a aparecer ese mismo id que genere una nueva agrupación, por ejemplo: id 2525 aparece tres veces agrupar esos datos, luego id 2526 aparece cuatro veces agrupar esos datos, luego vuelve a aparecer id 2525 y hacer una nueva agrupación por la cantidad de veces que aparezca, no sumar a la primera agrupación, adjunto imagen de tabla:

Comment: Bienvenido AleT a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Primero que nada, por favor agrega un ejemplo de los datos, tablas y consulta en forma de texto no de imagen y en segundo lugar ¿Cuál es el criterio o columna que se usaría para determinar que los primeros 2525 es un grupo y los siguientes es otro?